# Over-riding DRI Templates using xsl in DSpace

Tags: xslt, dspace

I'm working with DSpace 4.2 xmlui Mirage theme. I want to hide the *Communities and Collections* from the search results page.

[image]

By inspecting the DRI document of the page I found that the Communities and Collections results are added as:

```
<list id="aspect.discovery.SimpleSearch.list.comm-coll-result-list" n="comm-coll-result-list">
```

So I tried over-riding the template in the `xsl` file of the theme.

```
<xsl:template match="dri:list[@id='aspect.discovery.SimpleSearch.list.comm-coll-result-list']">
<!-- Over ride / remove the recent submissions box-->
</xsl:template>
```

But no change is reflected in the page. Am I doing something wrong here? I was able to hide the default search box in a similar manner by over-riding the template generating it's corresponding div.I noticed that the `list` item I want to hide is contained within another `div`. Is is not possible to over-ride a DRI element unless its tag is `div`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also add a [default filter query](https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC4x/Discovery#Discovery-Addingdefaultfilterqueries%28OPTIONAL%29) in your [dspace]/config/spring/api/discovery.xml.

> Default filter queries are applied on all search operations & sidebarfacet clicks. One useful application of default filter queries is ensuring that all returned results are items. **As a result, subcommunities and collections that are returned as results of the search operation, are filtered out**.

Relevant lines [here](https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/dspace-4.2/dspace/config/spring/api/discovery.xml#L126-L132), note that this is disabled by default. Uncomment to make this work.

```
<property name="defaultFilterQueries">
<list>
    <value>search.resourcetype:2</value>
</list>
```

Hope this help.

**UPDATE**

Copy the:

```
<property name="defaultFilterQueries">
    <list>
      <value>search.resourcetype:2</value>
    </list>
<property>
```

in the `<bean id="homepageConfiguration" class="org.dspace.discovery.configuration.DiscoveryConfiguration" scope="prototype">` because it overrides the defaultConfiguration as stated in this [comment](https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/dspace-4.2/dspace/config/spring/api/discovery.xml#L46).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I uncommented the lines, but communities and collections are still being returned in search.

Comment: Try running dspace index-discovery -b. Also please note that any modifications you made under the config directory needed restarting of your tomcat in order for your changes to take effect.

Comment: I ran index-discovery -b as well as index-discovery -f, and restarted tomcat, still no change.

Comment: You are using the `<entry key="default" value-ref="defaultConfiguration" />`. There is another entry below with `<entry key="site" value-ref="homepageConfiguration" />`. Since in the comment section it states that "**Use site to override the default configuration for the home page & default discovery page**" and you only have the defaultFilterQueries in the defaultConfiguration, your defaultConfiguration was overridden by the homepageConfiguration because it used the **key="site"**. Copy the defaultFilterQueries in the homepageConfiguration bean.

Answer (score 0):

The collection and community list results are displayed by the following XSLT: https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/master/dspace-xmlui/src/main/webapp/themes/dri2xhtml/structural.xsl#L3616-L3635

To change the display via XSLT, try constructing your own template code.

```
<xsl:template name="collectionSummaryList">
    <xsl:param name="handle"/>
    <xsl:param name="externalMetadataUrl"/>

    <xsl:variable name="metsDoc" select="document($externalMetadataUrl)"/>

    ...
</xsl:template>
```

If you completely suppress these results from your display, it will likely make your pagination counts unreliable.  It might make more sense to suppress the community/collection results from the SOLR search results.